# Python gnome keyring in bash mount script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am not sure if the title is correct, if not please edit it.

Now my problem is that I have a automated mount script written in bash and it runs when user logs in and asks for the users AD credentials to mount the Windows share.

```
#!/bin/bash
MOUNTDIR=
DIRNAME=
DOMAIN=
SERVER=
SHARE=

# create mountpoint for mounting
if [ ! -d ${HOME}/${DIRNAME} ]; then
        mkdir ${HOME}/${DIRNAME}
fi

## define a function that launched the zenity username dialog
get_username(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Username:"
}
# define a function that launched the zenity password dialog
get_password(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Password:" --hide-text
}

# attempt to get the username and exit if cancel was pressed.
wUsername=$(get_username) || exit

# if the username is empty or matches only whitespace.
while [ "$(expr match "$wUsername" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in username!" --text="Please check your username! Username field can not be empty!"  || exit
    wUsername=$(get_username) || exit
done

wPassword=$(get_password) || exit

while [ "$(expr match "$wPassword" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in password!" --text="Please check your password! Password field can not be empty!" || exit
    wPassword=$(get_password) || exit
done

# mount windows share to mountpoint
sudo mount -t cifs //$SERVER/$SHARE ${HOME}/${DIRNAME} -o username=${wUsername},password=${wPassword},domain=${DOMAIN}

# show if mounting was OK or failed
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        zenity --info --title="Mounting public share succeeded!" --text="Location Documents/Shares/public!"
else
        zenity --error --title="Mounting public did not succed!" --text="Please contact system administrator!"
fi
```

Now I have been looking at a blog called **Bending Gnome Keyring With Python** it explains the gnome keyring really well. But as I have never coded in python and never added python to bash then maybe someone here can show me how can I import gnome keyring to bash so it saves the users *username* and *password* so once the script is rerunned it takes the info from the gnome keyring.

Thank you. If you need more info please comment!

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that guide is a bit verbose, and dipping into Python seems unnecessary for your needs.  You would be served well by [gnome-keyring-query](https://gist.github.com/adamhotep/e5798989187b393789c1) (which you'll have to compile yourself).

The username can be pulled in from a command line option, or you can keep the prompt, or you can use `$USER` as a default.

First, add the password to the keyring:

```
echo -n "$wPassword" |gnome-keyring-query set WindowsAD
unset wPassword  # do not keep this in memory any longer than necessary
```

gnome-keyring-query does technically allow you to enter the password directly, but it stores the trailing linebreak from your <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keystroke and therefore will get it wrong.

To read it:

```
wUsername="$USER"
wPassword="$(gnome-keyring-query get WindowsAD)"
sudo mount ...
unset wPassword
```

From a security perspective, I'm not so happy seeing the password in the command line; anybody getting a full process list (e.g. `ps auxww`) would see it.  However, the only alternative I can see is to use `/etc/fstab.d` (use a file that only root can read, maybe even delete it after mounting).  That may be too cumbersome for you (or you may be on a system that does not support it).